# How to design with Paging of Gridview with additional options

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem that I want to design a gridview with additional options with paging in a different way which is shown in below images. I can implement simple paging concept in GridView but that will not shown like this which I desired as in images. This will show Records Per Page options also. Please suggest me any solution regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do a work around, by making a drop down list that is styled and placed riht under the gridview to make it look like part of the gridview, and then using the drop drown text change event update the gridview paging option.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer and tell me How it will be implemented.